# world of goo windows version, native in linux via installer possible?

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, games

I found an older game world of goo. Only the windows version. Is it possible to install it with an installer like NWN (nether winter night)?

I know i can install it with playonlinux, but this is over wine.

[here](https://github.com/liflg) I did not find it. Many things I found in www are outdated.

Comment: If you know there is a documented working path to installation (playonlinux), you should go that route. There's no expectation that Windows-only software should work on Linux so if someone else already figured it out- enjoy the benefits of their work to make it so

Comment: okay, thanks I installt it with playonlinux and test the game tomorrow. @Nmath